# How to include materialize-css npm package with webpack

Tags: css, npm, webpack, materialize, webpack-style-loader

I'm writing a client-side app that is using Webpack, and I cannot figure out how to require the materialize-css package. I'm using [Henrik Joreteg's hjs-webpack package](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack), and with this the yeticss npm package is included by doing an import in a sass file (e.g. `@import 'yeticss'`), but this doesn't work for materialize. Requiring it straight up in the code (e.g. `import 'materialize-css'` in a JS file) like any other package also doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In this case, unlike with *yeticss*, you need to go in and require the specific files, rather than just the package name, thus:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min';
```

Comment: thanks, this should be somewhere in the official documentation.

Comment: I changed this somewhat to import `materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js` and `materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css` since the package main pointed at /dist/js

Comment: As I understand, this goes into `.js` file, but what kind of import should be added to `.css` file?

Comment: @kolen you need to enable css-loader for this to work as shown. Both imports are for the js file.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), and I was able to execute:

```
yarn add materialize-css
```

And then in my `index.js` (top level react file):

```
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min';
```