# How and where to include materialize css in webpack using react

Tags: npm, webpack, reactjs, materialize, webpack-style-loader

I am learner to react js and webpack too. In my project, i had a style.css file, i can include it in my html,it works fine. But i want to use materialize css to add stylings. How to include the materialize css in webpack? can anyone suggest me how to do this?

First i did,

> npm install materialize-css --save

Then i add this in webpack at modules

> {
>                   test: /.css$/,
>                   loader: "style-loader!css-loader" ,
>                   include: /node_modules/
>               }
>    ,

I referred these links,
 [How to include materialize-css npm package with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435926/how-to-include-materialize-css-npm-package-with-webpack)

[How to use materialize-css with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499842/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-react)

But i don't understand where to exactly include and what to include for materialize css to be included in file, kindly someone help me out